# Alamofire 5.X Type of Expression is Ambiguous Without More Context

Tags: swift, alamofire

I've been debugging this for hours and I have discovered I absolutely despise Swift's error message of `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context` ---- This code worked with Alamofire 3, 4, and obviously with Alamofire 5 there's some changes to the way it works, but this is essentially what I've found elsewhere which means that something I'm doing is wrong but I have no g darn idea what it could be.

```
let urlString = "\(baseURL)\(header)"
let jsonData : Data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .prettyPrinted)
            
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
            
print("JSON Params->\(jsonString)")
            
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Authorization": "XXXXXX",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            ]
            
            
            let uploadUrl = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!, method: .post, headers: headers)
            AF.upload(
                multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in
                var keys = [String]()
                
                for (key, img) in images {
                    if let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressRatio) {
                        multiPart.append(imageData, withName: key, fileName: key+".png", mimeType: "image/png")
                        keys.append(key)
                    }
                }
                
                let jsonName = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["count": keys.count], options: .prettyPrinted)
                
                multiPart.append(jsonName, withName: "names")
                multiPart.append(jsonData, withName: "data")
            }, with: uploadUrl, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON{ response in
                        if hud{
                            Loader.init().hide(delegate: vc)
                        }
                        
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success(_):
                            print("Response->\(response.value)")
                            
                            if response.value != nil {
                                let JSON = response.value! as AnyObject
                                let response = JSON["response"] as! NSDictionary
                                
                                let success = response.value(forKey: "status")
                                let success_message = response.value(forKey: "success_message")
                                let error_message = response.value(forKey: "error_message")
                                
                                if success as! String {
                                    completion(response.replaceNullsWithBlanks() as NSDictionary, success_message as NSString, true)
                                } else {
                                    print("Upload failed")
                                    completion([:], error_message as NSString, false)
                                    
                                    if alertMsg {
                                        self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Alert", message: error_message, vc: vc)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break
                            
                        case .failure:
                            print(response.error ?? "Fail")
                            self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error!", message: (response.error?.localizedDescription)!, vc: vc)
                            break
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error!", message: error.localizedDescription, vc: vc)
                }
            })
```

Comment: Which line cause the issue? Unrelated, but: Don't use `NSString`, use directly `String`, that will avoid afterwards the `as String`. and `NSStuff` in general. Any reason why you don't use `Codable`?

Comment: @Larme full disclosure I am newer to Swift and I have taken over this app from some bad developers that were cheap. They had everything outdated so my first objective is to make sure I'm targeting an iOS that's current instead of 8+. I'll switch the object type to Codable

Comment: It seems like the error is after the encodingResult part. If I remove everything after the `with: uploadUrl` then the ambiguous error is gone but unsure why

Comment: I'd suggest to comment the whole `AF.upload(...)` code, and redo it. Start by writing it letter by letter, and let autocompletion helps you. I guess it should be now:  `AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in ... }, with: uploadUrl).response...`, there, there are various `responsePossibility`, use the one youo want, like `responseJSON()` (deprecatedd, but stilll working)

Comment: @Larme I ended up fixing it by switching it to `.responseDecodable` and making my own types, I'll update my answer with what worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it using `.responseDecoable`, I had to define my own Decodable

```
let urlString = "\(baseURL)\(header)"
            let jsonData : Data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .prettyPrinted)
            
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
            
            print("JSON Params->\(jsonString!)")
            
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
                "Authorization": "XXXXXX",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            ]
            
            struct DecodableType: Decodable {
                let success_message: String
            }
            
            struct UploadResponse: Decodable {
                let response: DecodableType
            }
            
            let uploadUrl = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!, method: .post, headers: headers)
            AF.upload(
                multipartFormData: { (multiPart) in
                var keys = [String]()
                
                for (key, img) in images {
                    if let imageData = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: compressRatio) {
                        multiPart.append(imageData, withName: key, fileName: key+".png", mimeType: "image/png")
                        keys.append(key)
                    }
                }
                
                let jsonName = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: ["count": keys.count], options: .prettyPrinted)
                
                multiPart.append(jsonName, withName: "names")
                multiPart.append(jsonData, withName: "data")
                }, with: uploadUrl).responseDecodable(of: UploadResponse.self) { response in
                    if hud {
                        Loader.init().hide(delegate: vc)
                    }
                    print("Result: \(response)")
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let result):
                        let response = result.response
                        completion([:], response.success_message as NSString, true)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        let err = error.localizedDescription
                        print("Upload Failed: \(err)")
                        completion([:], err as NSString, false)
                        if alertMsg {
                            self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error!", message: err, vc: vc)
                        }
                        break
                    }
                }
        } else {
            self.presentAlertWithTitle(title: "Error!", message: "Please check network connectivity.", vc: vc)
        }
```